# How to mock function only in tested class and not in unittest case

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, python-unittest

So i have unit test case class and a class that I want to test. There is a function in this class that has a function that I'm using to run this method that i am testing. To visualize the problem i will write some abstract code below:

```
import needed_module
from casual_class import CasualClass

class CasualClassTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.casual_class = CasualClass()

    def _run(self, func):
        result = needed_module.runner(func)
        return result

    @mock.patch('needed_module.runner', return_value='test_run_output')
    def test_get_that_item(self, mocked_runner):
        result = self._run(self.casual_class.get_that_item())
```

And the tested class:

```
import needed_module


class CasualClass:

    def get_that_item(self):
        #..some code..
        run_output = needed_module.runner(something)
        return something2
```

In this code get_that_item code wont even run because the runner is mocked. What i want to achieve is to run needed_module.runner original in test case and mocked one in the tested class. I've searched the internet for too long, to solve this...

Answer (score 0):

To achieve such a task I had to create an object of needed_module before patching the function and pass it to _run function in test case to use it.

```
class CasualClassTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.casual_class = CasualClass()

    def _run(self, func, runner=None):
        if not runner:
            result = needed_module.runner(func)
        else:
            result = runner(func)
        return result

    def test_get_that_item(self, mocked_runner):
        runner = needed_module.runner
        with mock.patch('needed_module.runner', return_value='test_run_output'):
            result = self._run(self.casual_class.get_that_item(), runner)
```